# Clipping TIN layers to pit shells

Tags: clip, arcscene, tin, volume

I have two TIN surfaces, one being a pit shell and a second being a horizontal layer which intersects the shell on all sides. I need to find out the volume between the intersection horizontal layer and the base of the pit, but I'm having trouble clipping the layer to the pit edges in order to do so,

[image]

Comment: What software are you using for the analysis?

Comment: Hi,ArcScene 10.2

Comment: have you tried using the [Cut and Fill tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000tz000000)? The section [How Cut and Fill works](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_Cut_Fill_works/009z000000vt000000/) gives a good explanation. When you said "_I'm having trouble clipping the layer to the pit edges_" what did you mean, do you have gaps between the surfaces?

Comment: Previously I have worked with a software package called Micromine, where in this situation I would be able to form a completely new closed multipatch, which would encompass the entire pit from the green layer, shown above, down to the current pit floor, hence providing me with the volumetric I am after.   Is this possible in ArcScene?

Answer (score 2):

The tools that you need are located within [ArcToolbox](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003q0000001m000000.htm) which can be accessed in ArcScene's tool bar or ArcGIS desktop. Look for this [icon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003q/GUID-E7DA877D-1790-4D85-A894-0E31F9E03067-web.png). Some of the tools that will allow you to calculate volume are as follows:

- [Surface Volume (3D Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000027000000)
- [Polygon Volume (3D Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000003q000000)
- [Cut and Fill](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000tz000000), here is a [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97492/calculating-volume-with-cut-fill-tool) to another question regarding this tool

If your horizontal layer has a fixed height/elevation, then Surface Volume (3D Analyst) should get you the results that you are after. Just make sure the processing extent is just for the pit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can export the two surfaces to (STL PLY) to CloudCompare ten Cork plugins in CloudCompare can generate intersection between two meshes.

Then use the mesh volume tool.